# html emails from contact form showing up differently in gmail ? Do you need to declare doctypes ?

Tags: php, html, email, gmail, html-email

We've recently changed our emails from running on 'horde' to running on gmail apps for buessiness, on our website we have a contact form that sends us the message wrapped in some html so that we can format it.

When the emails come through using the old system they come through fine, but when they come through in gmail they come through unformated with all the html tags showing.

Do you need to declare a doctype to get it to work properly, or is it somthing else ?

ive attached a copy of the php im using to send the emails

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="

<html>
<head>
<title>Message</title>

<style>
       h1   {font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; margin-top:20px;}
       p    {font-size:14px; margin-top:20px;}
</style> 

</head>
<body>
<h1>From :</h1> $name \n <h1>Email :</h1> $email \n <h1>Phone :</h1> $phone \n <h1>Message :</h1> $message
</body>
</html>
";

$recipient = "studio@mydomain.co.uk";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

echo("<p>Thanks for getting in touch, we'll get back to you shortly..</p>");
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GMail doesn't support `<style>` tags, you'll have to write them inline as `<h1 style="">` etc.

Check out [this table](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for a guide about what's supported in different email clients.

Answer (score 1):

GMail chooses non-html email if given the option.

[Reference](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/188-GMail-Chooses-ONLY-Non-HTML-Mail-If-Given-The-Option.htm)

Which you are doing here:

```
$mailheader .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```